# How can I go to a specific tab after a click event using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can I go to a specific tab after a click event, I tried `$("#tabs").tabs()` since every time I refresh it go back to its original but still does not work, what is the right way of doing it?

Here's my jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#btn").click(function() {
    //what to put here?
    //I tried this but do not work, since i notice every refresh it go back to its original tab
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
});
```

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="login">
</div>
<div id="register">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried $('#tabs').click()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `select` method of jquery ui tabs:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", "mytab"); // will switch to mytab
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

give this a try : `$('#tabs').triggerTab(2);`//2 here is the register tab

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a tabs with the selected option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: 3 });
```

Get or set the selected option, after init.

```
//getter
var selected = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the latest tab in a Cookie without too much extra code:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cookie

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
```

It'll always then return to the last tab you were on.

Then to go to a specific tab: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 3 );
```